# How to update each dependency in the package.json based on the node and npm versions

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to update the node version for my old project. I want to upgrade the node version from 6.10.3 to 12.22.7. So for that, I need to update the dependencies which are compatible with the updated node version. I am aware of updating all the dependencies to their latest versions. But is there any way to update based on the node and npm Compatability..?

I have thought of updating the node version to the latest. In that case, there can be more breaking changes that I need to handle and there are high chances which may affect my project structure as well.

The main technologies am using are sails, vue, angular, gulp, etc..

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `npm update`?

Comment: Tried, but didn't resolved my issue

Comment: Have you tried, updating to `12.22.7` then remove the `node_modules` and run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, First I removed node_modules, package-lock.json, updated to 12.22.7 and ran npm install command